# having a Grid control fill the parent container

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to get this Grid control to fill to the width of the parent container. I saw several references the HorizontialAlignment set to Stretch should work but for me it does nothing. The Grid is sized only to the Width of my largest textblock. I have tried setting the Width to 'auto' and nothing there either.

```
 <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="1" Height="75" Background="{StaticResource SteelBrush_Vert}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="0">
        <Viewbox Width="auto">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="AppGreeting" Text="Good Morning, User" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,4.6" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="WindowName" Text="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,4.6,4.6" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            </Grid>

        </Viewbox>

    </UniformGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Stretch="Fill"` property in your `Viewbox`

```
 <Viewbox Width="auto" Stretch="Fill">
            <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="7*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="18*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock x:Name="AppGreeting" Text="Good Morning, User" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5,0,4.6" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
                <TextBlock x:Name="WindowName" Text="Home" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,4.6,4.6" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            </Grid>
 </Viewbox>
```

Comment: It's Viewbox, not ViewBox: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.viewbox?view=netframework-4.8